# Select method failing when activate method succeeds!!! very strange

Tags: vba

I have written these VBA codes which work fine except for one issue. On the statement rs.activate I had earlier written rs.select which did not work.

My question is why rs.activate works here but not rs.select

```
Sub Extract_Data()

Checklist.Sheets.Add.Name = "DataNew"


Set msi = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MS Info")
Set rs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result")
Set tmp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")

Set evd = Checklist.Sheets("Evaluation Details")
Set smm = Checklist.Sheets("Summary")


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''few more codes''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''


rs.Activate

 With rs.Range("A2:H" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    .Value = .Value
 End With


 With rs.Range("N2:P" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    .Value = .Value
 End With

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''few more codes''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''

end sub
```

Comment: You wouldn't need `. Activate` nor `.Select` if you where using fully specified variables like `rs.Range("A2:H" & rs.Range("G" & rs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`. See [How to avoid select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). I also suggest declaring your variables and using `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated, you actually don't need to use `.Activate`, because you're specifying from which **Sheet** your **Range** is from.

You can safely remove any `.Activate` or `.Select` and your code will work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I removed rs.activate the code didnt work.

But later I figured out the real issue, I had missed to mention sheet object rs when specifying range G for counting last row.

Hence lastrow was counted on activesheet rather than rs sheet which lead to error finding no blank cell.
Well, thanks everyone for your comments and help. Really appreciate it!!!